How can i fix the runtime error in google colab, windows, chrome?
When i want to start runtime - run all for my code in windows chrom browser, this error apeared and running is stopped.
Failed to execute cell. Could not send execute message to run time: Typeerror: failed to fetch
Unable to connect to the runtime
how can i fix it?
Hi friends
When i want to start runtime - run all for my code in windows chrom browser, this error apeared and running is stopped.
Failed to execute cell. Could not send execute message to run time: Typeerror: failed to fetch
Unable to connect to the runtime
how can i fix Unable to connect to the runtime?

If you are connected to a university or organization network, you might encounter such issues. I would suggest changing your internet connection.
